# How to call a javascript function after remote delete with confirmation dialog in rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, actionlistener

I'm Using Rails3 and the Unobstrusive Javascript Gem [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/).

Remote deletion (without page reload) works well using code like:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :remote => :true, :title => "delete user, :class => "delete"%>
```

But how can I call a JavaScript function when the user clicks okay in the dialog? The goal is to hide a specific element on the site after the deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm right you just add delete.js.erb (with the js code you want to execute) in your users view folder :

```
    views/user/delete.js.erb
```

And in your users_controller.rb

```
    def delete

      #your controller code here

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js #this will call delete.js.erb when js action is called
      end
    end
```